# retrieve all the smallest strings from a set in python

Tags: python, string, list, set, min

I have a set which looks like

```
set(['A', 'BF', 'B', 'BA', 'ABF', 'AF', 'F', 'BFA', 'AFB', 'BAF', 'FA', 'FB', 'AB', 'FAB', 'FBA'])
```

and I'm trying to get all Strings which has the smallest length into a list
I tried using

```
print min((element for element in getParts(working_scheme,k)), key=len)
```

which just prints `A`but I need `['A', 'B', 'F']`

Ho can I accomplish this?

Comment: `A`, `B`, `F` are reasonable, but what's going on with `C`, `D` and `E`?

Comment: @ŁukaszR. sorry error of mine, Yeah A, B, F are reasonable and those are wanted sorry for slightly false example. Question is edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
>>> a_set = set(['A', 'BF', 'B', 'BA', 'ABF', 'AF', 'F', 'BFA', 'AFB', 'BAF', 'FA', 'FB', 'AB', 'FAB', 'FBA'])
>>> min_len = min( len(x) for x in a_set  )
>>> [ x for x in a_set if len(x) == min_len ]
['A', 'B', 'F']
```

**To split it up**

- `min_len = min( [ len(x) for x in a_set ] )` returns the minimum of the lengths.
- `[ x for x in a_set if len(x) == min_len ]` [List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), returns a list of elements which has length equals to `min_len`

Comment: You may drop brackets in `min_len` declaration - it won't build a list, but use lazy generator expression. So `min_len = min(len(x) for x in a_set)` is even better.

Comment: @ŁukaszR. Ohh.. I didn't knew that before. Thanks for the tip :D

Answer (score 0):

`min()` will only ever retrieve *one* result.

You'll have to code your own if you want to retrieve *all* shortest results:

```
shortest = []
shortest_length = float('inf')
for element in getParts(working_scheme, k):
    if len(element) < shortest_length:
        shortest = [element]
        shortest_length = len(element)
    elif len(element) == shortest_length:
        shortest.append(element)
```

This loops over the set just the once.

Answer (score 0):

Another method using a dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = set(['A', 'BF', 'B', 'BA', 'ABF', 'AF', 'F', 'BFA', 'AFB', 'BAF', 'FA', 'FB', 'AB', 'FAB', 'FBA'])
d = defaultdict(list)
for item in items:
    d[len(item)].append(item)
results = d[min(d)]
```

results:
['A', 'B', 'F']

Answer (score -1):

```
data = set(['A', 'BF', 'B', 'BA', 'ABF', 'AF', 'F', 'BFA', 'AFB', 'BAF', 'FA', 'FB', 'AB', 'FAB', 'FBA'])

_len = len(sorted(data, key=len)[0])
print filter(lambda x:len(x)==_len, data)
```

Returns:

```
['A', 'B', 'F']
```

Comment: You're better off calculating `len(min(data))` once, outside the lambda. Otherwise it will calculate the min again for every element. It should also be `len(min(data, key=len))`

Comment: for `data = ['AB', 'B']` it fails. Strings are compates lexicographically, and for first characters, 'A' is smaller than 'B'.